# Which pattern to choose?

Tags: architecture

I'm working on a desktop GUI (Qt+Python) app that handles invoices. So far I got 2 kinds of objects:

- ORM classes that describe invoices, products, customers, i.e. models.
- Views that allow browsing\editing of the models.

Each model can have multiple views.

And I got these kinds of code:

1. Code that initializes a model ("When creating a new invoice, the
   invoice date should be today")
2. Code that reacts to user changes in the view (“When customer is
   selected, set appropriate price level and recalculate all prices and
   amounts”)
3. Code that does obvious validation on the fly (“Invoice date can’t be
   empty! A product must be selected!”)
4. Code that validates the invoice against business rules (“The product
   is not in stock”, “The sale amount exceeds the customer’s credit”).

So the question is – which design pattern should I choose? The aim would be avoiding code duplication and allow for rapid changes to the models and views. 
So far I’ve been thinking about simple model-view approach, with 1&4 belonging to the model itself. But the 2&3 give me a pause.  Should I use MVC and put 2&3 into a controller? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think looking at the Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) pattern will be valuable for you:  http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

You have models that are views, and models that are entities.  Your view model logic shouldn't get shipped into the Controller, the controller should be dispatching events to it.

So, in your example #2 you say:  When a customer is selected, set appropriate price level and recalculate...   A customer being "selected" is part of some domain object, whether it is an "order" or a "transaction" or some such.   This domain object may not be the Order entity, but the OrderProcess domain view, which has a bunch of "views" associated with it (like price lists).

Comment: Thanks, I've read it. AFAIU, this pattern proposes introduction of a second model that is tasked with doing validation\enforcing BRs etc. leaving the first model to read the data from the DB. Maybe I am missing something, but how does that benefit my scenario? It's not that my reading functionality is so complicated to require a separate model.

Comment: Ok, so is the "recalculated price list" just a list of entities from the database?  There is some kind of domain model present there, and that domain model should be deciding what entities need updating when the customer selected action comes in from the controller.

Comment: Model != database entity, it can, but it more often has more complexity than that.

Comment: Oh, I get the feeleing I lack theoretical basis needed to support this discussion... Gota go and educate myself some more on the subject. Thanks for your replies!